# How to connect Eclipse ADT emulator to an Android Device with my laptop Bluetooth?

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth, eclipse-adt

I want to test my bluetooth based app, but I don't have two devices. Is there any way to do this using my laptop bluetooth for Eclipse ADT? What settings should I use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Emulator does not support Bluetooth. You can check [limitation of Emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#limitations). You cant set bluetooth setting for Eclipse ADT. It depends on your App that which requirements are needed. If there is only connection bases program then u can connect to your laptop bluetooth from your Android Device using your Application.Otherwise you need Two Android devices.

Still you can check this :

1. [Debug a Bluetooth App with Android Emulator on PC](http://technoga.wordpress.com/2013/05/06/debug-a-bluetooth-app-with-android-emulator-on-pc/)
2. [Bluetooth support on Android Emulator](http://niro-offonatangent.blogspot.in/2011/06/bluetooth-support-on-android-emulator.html)